# Youtube Oauth 2.0 asp.net Server-side web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, youtube.net-api

Is there any library for server-side web applications for Youtube Oauth 2.0? It seams that the youtube library webpage don't work? Link below

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Client_Libraries

Comment: The page seems to work fine...

Comment: The link is working but not the link to the client library on that page. This link https://developers.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2